# Use AWS CLI to Copy from S3 to EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, command-line-interface

I have zipped files in an S3 bucket that I need to bring back to my EC2 instance.  In the past, I moved the documents to S3 with the following command:

```
aws s3 cp /my/ec2/path/ s3://my/s3/path/ --exclude '*' --include '2014-01*’ —-recursive
```

To move files from January 2014 back to EC2, I have tried the following command:

```
aws s3 cp s3://my/s3/path/ //my/ec2/path/ --exclude '*' --include '2014-01*' --recursive
```

My understanding is that this command excludes all files but then includes all files with the prefix '2014-01'.  I have confirmed that this is how the files I want start. I have also tried only one forward slash before mainstorage and including fewer files.

I have followed these two links from Amazon:

- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/index.html
- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/using-s3-commands.html

Answer (score 8):

Figured it out.  The key was to define the filepath in --include , i.e. --include '*2014-1*'.  Correct command:

```
aws s3 cp s3://my/s3/path //my/ec2/path/ --exclude '*' --include '*2014-01*' --recursive
```